# How to configure Vagrant + Apache + Passenger with Rack-based application?

Tags: ruby, apache, vagrant, passenger, rack

I'm studying Ruby and trying to run [this application](https://github.com/IvanShamatov/rails-like-app) on Vagrant using Apache and Passenger. The application works fine if I run it on my local computer, but it only shows 404 "nothing found" page if I try to run it on Vagrant.
I guess my problem is that I can't write all the configurations in Vagrantfile and Apache properly. I have the page 404 from my application, therefore it works. But it shows 404 on any URL I try to enter.
VagrantFile includes:

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder "./html/", "/var/www/html"
```

and also provision (installing apache2, Ruby 2.3.3, RVM and passenger)

in  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    PassengerRuby /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby

<Directory /var/www/html/public>
      PassengerEnabled on
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
</Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

in html folder I also have required for apache folders (tmp and public)

Comment: how do you run/start your app ? how do you access it ?

Comment: I only run "vagrant up" command and then I go to 127.0.0.1:8080, apache configuration is changed by shell script from vagrant provision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the REQUEST_PATH variable has another name on Apache (REQUEST_URI), that is why router always gave back "Nothing found".
So I just changed this variable and everything work right now.